# Could anyone debunk these theories stating why hinduism is false?

Tags: gods, brahman

So i’ve recently come across these videos stating reasons hinduism is false and i am not sure how these can be refuted , i was wondering is someone could help me and go through each point thoroughly to explain to me? Start from the bottom.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/xn686x0b937exj697xk9e/h?rlkey=oqcvius6x0oy0mkmh9kff01o4&dl=0

Thank you.

Comment: Let us not promote tiktok in this forum. Replace those links with the summary/key points mentioned in such videos in your question description instead.

Comment: Since Tiktok has been banned in India, where most Hindus live, it is very unlikely that most will be able to access the links provided.

Comment: We cannot access the links. You can provide a gist of their refutations and we debunk them

Comment: easy way to debunk these theories - stop watching tiktok.

Comment: ive added it to a document

Comment: It might be better if you summarize some of the points here, so people can read them. (I checked the link, but it seemed to be full of screenshots - it's a lot of files.) If there are too many points, how about just presenting them here one by one?